# gh-pages not deploying website which runs locally

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-pages

I had hosted this website on Github's gh-pages. [Source Code](https://github.com/sudoankit/web-resume)

It's not loading it. This is the website : [web-resume](https://sudoankit.github.io/web-resume/)

After searching and looking up I believe the error lies in this line `Typer.file="https://sudoankit.github.io/web-resume/themeat.txt";`

in this fragment of `Javascript` code.

```
var Typer={
text: null,
accessCountimer:null,
index:0, // current cursor position
speed:1, // speed of the Typer
file:"", //file, must be set
accessCount:0, //times alt is pressed for Access Granted
deniedCount:0, //times caps is pressed for Access Denied
init: function(){// inizialize Hacker Typer
    accessCountimer=setInterval(function(){Typer.updLstChr();},500); // inizialize timer for blinking cursor
    $.get(Typer.file,function(data){// get the text file
        Typer.text=data;// save the textfile in Typer.text
        Typer.text = Typer.text.slice(0, Typer.text.length-1);
    });
},

content:function(){
    return $("#console").html();// get console content
},

write:function(str){// append to console content
    $("#console").append(str);
    return false;
},

makeAccess:function(){//create Access Granted popUp      FIXME: popup is on top of the page and doesn't show is the page is scrolled
    Typer.hidepop(); // hide all popups
    Typer.accessCount=0; //reset count
    var ddiv=$("<div id='gran'>").html(""); // create new blank div and id "gran"
    ddiv.addClass("accessGranted"); // add class to the div
    ddiv.html("<h1>ACCESS GRANTED</h1>"); // set content of div
    $(document.body).prepend(ddiv); // prepend div to body
    return false;
},
makeDenied:function(){//create Access Denied popUp      FIXME: popup is on top of the page and doesn't show is the page is scrolled
    Typer.hidepop(); // hide all popups
    Typer.deniedCount=0; //reset count
    var ddiv=$("<div id='deni'>").html(""); // create new blank div and id "deni"
    ddiv.addClass("accessDenied");// add class to the div
    ddiv.html("<h1>ACCESS DENIED</h1>");// set content of div
    $(document.body).prepend(ddiv);// prepend div to body
    return false;
},

hidepop:function(){// remove all existing popups
    $("#deni").remove();
    $("#gran").remove();
},

addText:function(key){//Main function to add the code
    if(key.keyCode==18){// key 18 = alt key
        Typer.accessCount++; //increase counter 
        if(Typer.accessCount>=3){// if it's presed 3 times
            Typer.makeAccess(); // make access popup
        }
    }else if(key.keyCode==20){// key 20 = caps lock
        Typer.deniedCount++; // increase counter
        if(Typer.deniedCount>=3){ // if it's pressed 3 times
            Typer.makeDenied(); // make denied popup
        }
    }else if(key.keyCode==27){ // key 27 = esc key
        Typer.hidepop(); // hide all popups


    }else if(Typer.text){ // otherway if text is loaded
        var cont=Typer.content(); // get the console content
        if(cont.substring(cont.length-1,cont.length)=="|") // if the last char is the blinking cursor
            $("#console").html($("#console").html().substring(0,cont.length-1)); // remove it before adding the text
        if(key.keyCode!=8){ // if key is not backspace
            Typer.index+=Typer.speed;   // add to the index the speed
        }else{
            if(Typer.index>0) // else if index is not less than 0 
                Typer.index-=Typer.speed;// remove speed for deleting text
        }
        var text=Typer.text.substring(0,Typer.index)// parse the text for stripping html enities
        var rtn= new RegExp("\n", "g"); // newline regex

        $("#console").html(text.replace(rtn,"<br/>"));// replace newline chars with br, tabs with 4 space and blanks with an html blank
        window.scrollBy(0,100); // scroll to make sure bottom is always visible
    }
    if ( key.preventDefault && key.keyCode != 122 ) { // prevent F11(fullscreen) from being blocked
        key.preventDefault()
    };  
    if(key.keyCode != 122){ // otherway prevent keys default behavior
        key.returnValue = false;
    }
},

updLstChr:function(){ // blinking cursor
    var cont=this.content(); // get console 
    if(cont.substring(cont.length-1,cont.length)=="|") // if last      char is the cursor
$("#console").html($("#console").html().substring(0,cont.length-1));    // remove it
    else
        this.write("|"); // else write it
}
}
function replaceUrls(text) {
var http = text.indexOf("http://");
var space = text.indexOf(".me ", http);
if (space != -1) { 
    var url = text.slice(http, space-1);
    return text.replace(url, "<a href=\""  + url + "\">" + url + "</a>");
} else {
return text
}
}
Typer.speed=3.14;
Typer.file="https://sudoankit.github.io/web-resume/themeat.txt"; //error here?
Typer.init();

var timer = setInterval("t();", 30);
function t() {
Typer.addText({"keyCode": 123748});
if (Typer.index > Typer.text.length) {
    clearInterval(timer);
   }
}
```

The website runs smoothly locally.
It really would be helpful if there's a workout.

Comment: After fixing the `https` issue I would also suggest to check the page with an html validator and fix any issues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple to locate problem in browser dev tools console.

Site is running on `https` protocol and due to mixed content policies isn't loading jQuery from `http`

Try using protocol relative url for jQuery library. Then it will load properly regardless of running on local http or remote on https

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note also that version 1.4 is very very old

Comment: Use your browser console while working with javascript. It's your first line of troubleshooting